# Linux is slow in authenticating password

Tags: linux, ssh, key-authentication, putty

I started using PuTTY public and private key pairs recently to login my local virtual machine using ssh.

Initially, it worked quite fast. From asking username to starting a shell/command, it took less than 1 second to complete.

However, I installed another virtual machine in my VirtualBox and this is where my first virtual machine login becomes slow. The following is the event log of my first virtual machine.

```
2021-03-13 10:05:36 Pageant has 1 SSH-2 keys
2021-03-13 10:05:36 Pageant key #0 matches configured key file
2021-03-13 10:05:37 Trying Pageant key #0
2021-03-13 10:05:39 Sending Pageant's response
2021-03-13 10:05:39 Access granted
2021-03-13 10:05:39 Opening session as main channel
2021-03-13 10:05:41 Opened main channel
2021-03-13 10:05:41 Allocated pty (ospeed 38400bps, ispeed 38400bps)
2021-03-13 10:05:41 Started a shell/command
```

As shown above, it took 2 seconds to try Pageant key and open a session as main channel.

I did not have this issue previously, which means that all events above used to take 0 second to complete all of them. But I have been experiencing the slowness recently and have no idea how to resolve it.

Also, when I `su` to another user, after inputting password, I need to wait for 2 to 3 seconds for linux to verify.

I do not have this problem when I ssh to another remote server. So I think the problem lies in my virtual machine.

Comment: As a stab in the dark, this may be due to DNS queries not being resolved and timing out. Any DNS resolver logfiles around?

Comment: Yeah, in my experience slow log-ins are 99% down to a broken DNS setup or broken connectivity to DNS servers.

Comment: @David Tonhofer May I know how to get DNS resolver log files?

Comment: Just try running random DNS queries, like `time nslookup abc.com` and `time nslookup 1.2.3.4` - in a perfect world they should take less than a second to complete. If they take a lot more or time out - here's your problem.

Comment: I get the following after running  time nslookup 1.2.3.4

```real    0m0.132s```

```user    0m0.009s```

```sys     0m0.010s```

Comment: Getting the logfiles depends on the setup. However, if you try to log in using an IP address instead of a name, do things improve?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer No, the same problem occurs even if I use IP address or hostname using PuTTY.

Comment: Does this happen when one of the two VMs is shut down? Resource problems maybe? Excessive swapping?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Let's say the problem occurs in VM A. Initially, when I have VM A only, it does not have any delay problem in authenticating password. However, after I install a new VM (say VM B), VM A started experiencing delay in authenticating password, but other commands are fine. I thought the issue is that VM B is giving the problem, so I deleted VM B. However, after the deletion, the problem in VM A remains.